# Why is AWS::S3::S3Object complaining undefined method delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Gemfile:

gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'aws-s3'

When deletion of video is called, this method is also called in video model:

```
 def remove_encoded_video
    unless output_url.blank?
      AWS::S3.new(
        :access_key_id     => zencoder_setting["s3_output"]["access_key_id"],
        :secret_access_key => zencoder_setting["s3_output"]["secret_access_key"]
      )
      AWS::S3::S3Object.delete(File.basename(output_url), zencoder_setting["s3_output"]["bucket"])    
      AWS::S3::S3Object.delete("/thumbnails_#{self.id}/frame_0000.png", zencoder_setting["s3_output"]["bucket"])
    end
  end
```

These two:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.delete(File.basename(output_url), zencoder_setting["s3_output"]["bucket"])

AWS::S3::S3Object.delete("/thumbnails_#{self.id}/frame_0000.png", zencoder_setting["s3_output"]["bucket"])
```

caused

NoMethodError in VideosController#destroy

undefined method `delete' for AWS::S3::S3Object:Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the two gems 'aws-sdk' and 'aws-s3' are compatible.  You should be using only one of them.

The aws-sdk version of AWS::S3::S3Object does not have a delete method at the class level, only on the instance level.  So you need to create the S3Object first, then call delete on the S3Object if you use 'aws-sdk'.

Assuming your code is taken from the docs for aws-s3, it may just work if you remove `gem 'aws-sdk'` from your Gemfile and re-bundle.  Of course that may break other code in your app if you're using 'aws-sdk' elsewhere.

UPDATE:

You can get and delete the S3Object as follows:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => '...',
                 :secret_access_key => '...')

bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
object = bucket.objects[key]
object.delete
```

where bucket_name is the name of the bucket, and key in the key of the object you wish to delete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to establish connection with aws-sdk and delete?

Comment: Thanks. It worked except that "aws-s3" and "aws-sdk" can be used at the same time. Your solution is to use "aws-s3".

Comment: and how do you get the key? by iterating 10000's of objects from the bucket? don't know why people leave incomplete answers.